# How to return NULL as a specific string in a SQL query result?

Tags: sql, oracle, null, coalesce

I am trying to return `NULL` as a string in the view when queried, but don't really understand how.

For the column it either has data or returns `NULL`, but if it returns `NULL` I want it to say something else.

```
SELECT lib_item_id "Library Item ID",
       title "Library Item Name", 
       date_of_purchase "Year of Purchase",
       coalesce(pub_id, null) as "Publisher ID"
  FROM lib.Library_items 
 WHERE date_of_purchase > '31-DEC-10'
 ORDER BY "Library Item Name" asc;
```

Comment: COALESCE http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions023.htm

Comment: What version of Oracle are you using?  If ancient, then it might not support `coalesce()`.

Comment: Have you tried using the `NVL()` function? you can use it as `select NVL(yourcolumn,'value_if_its_null') from table`

Comment: This helped! My string was in double quotes rather than single quotes. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
select coalesce(some_column, 'some default string') as some_column
from your_table
```

or

```
select case when some_column is null
            then 'some default string'
            else some_column 
       end as some_column
from your_table
```

Comment: The issue I have received when trying this is "invalid identifier" and has led me to be stuck since I had initially looked up coalesce

Comment: Tried the second method and it worked. Thanks for help, I will continue to see why coalesce did not work for me.

Edit: string was in double quotes instead of single, thank you for the help!